# Render Markdown in place of text not in a separate preview window

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, markdown

Does anyone know of a project that does this?

Every markdown project I find separates the markdown from the preview window. I want something where as you are writing the markdown it renders right there, as you type. Like Dropbox paper.

Anyone aware of anything?

Thanks

Comment: I've seen the same kinda editor on https://hackpad.com/. The code is open sourced under https://github.com/dropbox/hackpad. You can check them out

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a react component available for it

Comment: Does `reactjs` tag suggest that you are seeking help in writing your own React component to do that?

Comment: @EugZol That's preferred but anything works! I actually just came accross this project by Facebook that might do what I want! https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/

Answer (score 0):

[StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) is a web application which does this and does it well. It's open source and the code is [on github](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit). It appears to be written in Vue.js.

If you want to build your own such component using React, I would investigate the [Slate](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate) editor framework. They even have a simple [in-place markdown preview](http://slatejs.org/#/markdown-preview) example.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to 2023, try https://lexical.dev/ successor of draft-js by meta

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Are you asking if I am affiliated with meta? Then no, something I used for my project and it’s solid!